# Find click in between two divisions using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have two divisions with id `one` and `two`, as the division `two` inside the division `one`. Now O want to alert ONE if I clicked inside `one` but outside `two` and to alert TWO if I clicked inside `two`.

Here is what I have tried.

HTML:

```
<div id="one">
  ONE ONE<br>ONE ONE<br>
  <div id="two">
    TWO TWO<br>TWO TWO<br>
  </div>
  ONE ONE<br>ONE ONE<br>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$("div").click(function(event){
    var target = $(event.target);
    if(target.is("two")){
        alert("two");
    }else{
        alert("one");
    }
});
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have nested divs, both with event handlers, but only want one event, you need to use

```
event.stopPropagation();
```

the first thought would be to use `event.preventDefault()` but:

> The preventDefault() method does not prevent further propagation of an event through the DOM. Use the stopPropagation() method to handle this.

[ref](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_preventdefault.asp)

Secondingly, the `.is` function takes a selector as an argument, so would be a class selector (`.class`) or an id (`#id`).

Giving your updated code:

```
$("div").click(function(event){
    var target = $(event.target);
    if(target.is("#two")){
        // don't bubble up to get two events
        event.stopPropagation();
        alert("two");
    }else{
        alert("one");
    }
});
```

Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/phubzq68/

Answer (score 1):

```js
$("#one").click(function(event) {
  alert("one");
});
$("#two").click(function(event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
  alert("two");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="one">
  ONE ONE
  <br>ONE ONE
  <br>
  <div id="two">
    TWO TWO
    <br>TWO TWO
    <br>
  </div>
  ONE ONE
  <br>ONE ONE
  <br>
</div>
```

1. Have separate click for both
2. Then use `event.StopPropagation()` to avoid bubbling up

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("div").click(function(){
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        switch (id) { 
            case 'one': 
                alert('one');
                break;
            case 'two': 
                alert('two');
                break;
     });
});
```

Note: untested

Comment: Thanks for your response :) But it is not working :( Can you make a working fiddle for me.